# AS3 & Flex: Optimize event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

The problem I want to solve today is different than most problems. I want to make the application execute the handlers more rapidly so that I don't see any lag in the UI.

I have a class that contains a `TextInput` and a generated dashed line, consisting of a series of lines. This component, let's call it `CardTextInput`, listens to the parent state changes. If the mouse is over the area, the dashed line is shown, otherwise hidden.

Everything works great if there is only one instance of `CardTextInput`, if I add 10, when I mouse over it takes 0.5 seconds to show the dashed lines compared to the case when there's only one and it is shown instantly.

How could I optimize such a scenario?

Comment: It's difficult to tell someone how to optimize their code without seeing any code.

Comment: `consisting of a series of lines`: assuming you mean many instances of Line, try using one instance of Path instead. Might speed up the rendering. In any case, the event listeners are not your bottleneck if there's only 10 of them. However - as @SunilD. pointed out - it's impossible to be more precise if you don't share any code.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you add 10 CardTextInput in parent myCanvas.

Try to set the CardTextInput'mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false

Then add MouseMove event listener on myCanvas

```
myCanvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);

for each (var child:DisplayObject in myCanvas) {
     child.dashLines.mouseEnabled = false;
     child.dashLines.mouseChildren = false;
}  

protected function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {

    for each (var child:DisplayObject in myCanvas) {
        child.dashLines.visible = false;
    }  

    for each (child in myCanvas) {

         if (child.hitTestPoint(event.stageX, event.stageY)) {
             child.dashLines,visible = true;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I used to show the dashed line in a different state using `includeIn`, now I changed it to visible on that state and everything is faster. That improved it :)

Comment: I don't know how includeIn works, but I guess it may cause calculation about position or something else. And less mouse event listener could make the performance better.

Comment: This is your answer right here. It is the number one thing you can do to optimize mouse handlers an many objects at once.

Comment: Ah, i just saw his comment. He was simply noticing creation time. The fix of course being to create early and toggle visibility.